# In JMeter 5.6.2, Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException

Tags: jmeter

I am getting following error on JMeter for internal site. Site opens successfully on browser but when I set it up on JMeter then getting below error. My company no longer having proxies in our environment.

Response code:Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException
Response message:Non HTTP response message: Connection reset

Internal site I am trying
https://peoplesoftportaltest/Default.asp?
https://peoplesoftportaltest/SA_QUESTIONNAIRE.asp

I have done the following setting :

user.properties : httpclient4.retrycount=1 and hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters
hc.parameters : http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to your website using [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl-s_client.html) and see protocol version and algorithms used. Alternatively use a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to capture SSL handshare details from the browser.

Then [enable JMeter debug logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file

```
<Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
```

and [Java SSL/TLS connections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) by adding the next line to *system.properties* file

```
javax.net.debug=all
```

and see jmeter.log file and stdout for the protocol and cypher used.

Amend JMeter's configuration so it would do the same as the real browser and it should resolve your problem.